# Как правильно поставить защиту

Tags: php

Нашел такую вот защиту:

```
<?php
$ip=getenv('REMOTE_ADDR');
class InitVars {
// Недопустимые слова в запросах
var $deny_words = array("union","char","players","from","truncate","table","select","update","drop","delete","benchmark", "order", "limit", "UNION","CHAR", "DROP", "FROM", "SELECT", "UPDATE", "DELETE", "ORDER", "PLAYERS", "TRUNCATE", "LIMIT", "TABLE", "Union","Players","From","Truncate","Table","Select","Update","Char","Drop","Delete","Benchmark","Order","Limit", "or","OR","Or","and","AND","And");

function InitVars() {
}

// Метод конвентирует суперглобальные массивы $_POST, $_GET в перемнные
// Например : $_GET['psw'] будет переобразовано в $psw с тем же значением
function convertArray2Vars () {

        foreach($_GET as $_ind => $_val) {
                global $$_ind;
                if(is_array($$_ind)) $$_ind = htmlspecialchars(stripslashes($_val));
        }

        foreach($_POST as $_ind => $_val) {
                global $$_ind;
                if(is_array($$_ind)) $$_ind = htmlspecialchars(stripslashes($_val));

        }
}

// Метод проверяет $_GET и $_POST переменные на наличие опасных данных и SQL инъекций
function checkVars() {
        //Проверка опасных данных.
        foreach($_GET as $_ind => $_val) {
                        $_GET[$_ind] = htmlspecialchars(stripslashes($_val));

                        $exp = explode(" ",$_GET[$_ind]);
                        foreach($exp as $ind => $val) {
                                if(in_array($val,$this->deny_words)) $this->antihack("Послушайте, мои маленькие хакеры... Несанкционированный доступ в БД карается лишением свободы на срок от 3-х до 5-ти лет. <br>Вам ведь не нужны проблемы?. ");
                        }
        }

        foreach($_POST as $_ind => $_val) {
                        $_POST[$_ind] = htmlspecialchars(stripslashes($_val));

                        $exp = explode(" ",$_POST[$_ind]);
                        foreach($exp as $ind => $val) {
                                if(in_array($val,$this->deny_words)) $this->antihack("Послушайте, мои маленькие хакеры... Несанкционированный доступ в БД карается лишением свободы на срок от 3-х до 5-ти лет. <br>Вам ведь не нужны проблемы?.");
                        }
        }

}

function antihack($msg) {
    echo "<font color='red'><b>Ошибка: </b></font>$msg<br>\n";
    die;
}

}
function GotoTranslit($var){
$NpjLettersFrom = "абвгдезиклмнопрстуфцы";
$NpjLettersTo   = "abvgdeziklmnoprstufcy";
$NpjBiLetters = array(
"й"=>"y","ё"=>"jo","ж"=>"zh","х"=>"kh","ч"=>"ch",
"ш"=>"sh","щ"=>"sch","э"=>"e","ю"=>"yu","я"=>"ya",
"ъ"=>"","ь"=>"",);
$NpjBLettersFrom = "АБВГДЕЗИКЛМНОПРСТУАЦЫ";
$NpjBLettersTo   = "ABVGDEZIKLMNOPRSTUACY";
$NpjBiGLetters = array(
"Й"=>"Y","Ё"=>"JO","Ж"=>"ZH","Х"=>"KH","Ч"=>"CH",
"Ш"=>"SH","Щ"=>"SCH","Э"=>"E","Ю"=>"YU","Я"=>"YA",
"Ъ"=>"","Ь"=>"",);
$NpjCaps  = "АБВГДЕЁЖЗИЙКЛМНОПРСТУФХЦЧШЩЬЪЫЭЮЯ";
$NpjSmall = "абвгдеёжзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщьъыэюя";
$var = str_replace(".php","",$var);
$var = trim(strip_tags($var));
$var = preg_replace( "/\s+/ms","_",$var );
$var = strtr( $var,$NpjBiGLetters );
$var = strtr( $var,$NpjBLettersFrom,$NpjBLettersTo );
$var = strtr( $var,$NpjLettersFrom,$NpjLettersTo );
$var = strtr( $var,$NpjBiLetters );
$var = preg_replace("/[^a-z0-9\_\-.]+/mi","",$var);
$var = preg_replace('#[\-]+#i','_',$var);
$var = str_replace('_',' ',$var);
return $var;
}
function mclose() {
if (@mysql_ping()) {@mysql_close();}
}

function ip2int($ip) {
$a=explode(".",$ip);
return $a[0]*256*256*256+$a[1]*256*256+$a[2]*256+$a[3];
}
function htmlEncode($txt) {
return htmlspecialchars($txt,ENT_QUOTES);
}
function htmlDecode($txt) {
return htmlspecialchars_decode($txt,ENT_QUOTES);
}

while (list($key,$val) = @each($_GET)) {
if (!is_array($val)) {
$$key = htmlEncode($val);$_GET["$key"] = $$key;
}else {
$$key = array();
$tmp = array();
while (list($kkey,$vval) = @each($val)) {
if (!is_array($vval)) {
$tmp[$kkey] = htmlEncode($vval);
}else {
$tmp2 = array();
while (list($kkkey,$vvval) = @each($vval)) {
$tmp2[$kkkey] = htmlEncode($vvval);
}
$tmp[$kkey]=$tmp2;
}
}
$$key = $tmp;$_GET["$key"] = $tmp;
}
}
while (list($key,$val) = @each($_POST)) {
if (!is_array($val)) {
$$key = htmlEncode($val);$_POST["$key"] = $$key;
}else {
$$key = array();
$tmp = array();
while (list($kkey,$vval) = @each($val)) {
if (!is_array($vval)) {
$tmp[$kkey] = htmlEncode($vval);
}else {
$tmp2 = array();
while (list($kkkey,$vvval) = @each($vval)) {
$tmp2[$kkkey] = htmlEncode($vvval);
}
$tmp[$kkey]=$tmp2;
}
}
$$key = $tmp;$_POST["$key"] = $tmp;
}
}

?>
```

Вопросик, как ее правильно установить,
1) Кидать в каждый файлик на сайте
2) Или же создать отдельный файл def.php и к нему с каждой страницу вот таким образом `include 'def.php';` Подключаться ?

Comment: @oOKomarOo, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку 101010 редактора.

Comment: второе[]()

Comment: `// Метод конвентирует суперглобальные массивы $_POST, $_GET в перемнные
// Например : $_GET['psw'] будет переобразовано в $psw с тем же значением`

Дальше читать не стал...

Comment: Ага. После register_globals вручную - весь остальной текст меркнет и не достоин ни капли внимания :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Используйте нормальный фреймворк с эскейпингом выводимых в шаблон данных, хранимых в БД.
2. Используйте prepared statement для всех обращений к БД.

И шаткие велосипеды вам не понадобятся. А то в итоге получится как с [femme fatale](http://habrahabr.ru/post/135271/).